# Why autoloader error comes in symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.2

can any one please let me know why the autoloader error is comes in symfony2.
what is parmenanat solution of it. i have download the symfony2 version with vendor and all the things is working properly accept when i insert a custom class and try to use it always raise an auto load error please give me it's solution . error msg is as bellow.

```
The autoloader expected class "Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Enquiry" 
to be defined in file
"D:\wamp\www\Symfony/src/\Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Enquiry.php". 
The file was found but the class was not in it, 
the class name or namespace probably has a typo.
```

here is enquiry class.

```
<?php

namespace Blogger\BlogBungle\Entity;

class Enquiry
{

protected $name;
protected $email;
protected $subject;
protected $body;

public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;

}
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
}
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;
}
public function getSubject()
{
    return $this->subject;
}
public function setSubject($subject)
{
    $this->subject = $subject;
}
public function getBody()
{
    return $this->body;
}
public function setBody($body)
{
    $this->body = $body;
}


}


?>
```

Comment: Post your class `Enquiry` please.

Comment: no still it's shows the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the difference between

```
namespace Blogger\BlogBungle\Entity;
```

and

```
 Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Enquiry
```

in error message? **BlogBungle should be BlogBundle** when you define your namespace.